# Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred

Tags: r

Whenever i try to run this piece of code:

```
omnibus[[scenario1$scnid]] <-  
      runTheSim(from = simStart, to = simEnd, scen = scenario1,
                  dmS = dmStatus, fcS = fcStatus, icS = icStatus,
                  dmF = demandFun, fcF = forecastFun, olF = oulFun, 
                  rec1 = oneRecord, recs = allRecords,
                  store1 = empty1Store, stores = allStores)
```

I keep getting the same error:

```
  Start on simulating inventory for scenario nAppr+dlp+1 from 20 to 2020.
  Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.
  Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Running `rlang::last_error()` and `rlang::last_trace()` shows the following:

```
<error/vctrs_error_scalar_type>
Input must be a vector, not NULL.
Backtrace:
 1. global::runTheSim(...)
 5. vctrs:::stop_scalar_type(.Primitive("quote")(NULL), "")
 6. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(msg, "vctrs_error_scalar_type", actual = x)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
>   rlang::last_trace()
<error/vctrs_error_scalar_type>
Input must be a vector, not NULL.
Backtrace:
    █
 1. ├─global::runTheSim(...)
 2. │ └─dplyr::lag(stores[[fctidx]]) sics.R:84:4
 3. │   ├─vctrs::vec_c(...)
 4. │   └─vctrs::vec_slice(inputs$x, seq_len(xlen - n))
 5. └─vctrs:::stop_scalar_type(.Primitive("quote")(NULL), "")
 6.   └─vctrs:::stop_vctrs(msg, "vctrs_error_scalar_type", actual = x)
```

A friend of mine runs the same code and doesnt get an error, but a loop of 30.

Can you help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, it is not possible without providing something reproducible. Where does the `runTheSim` function come from? What data is being used?

Answer (score -2):

```
icIni <- list(leadtime = 5, review = 3, fixedConstant = 8, csl = 0.9)
str(icIni)
icIni[[1]] #or# 
icIni$leadtime
icIni$safetyfactor <- qnorm(icIni$csl) # (unit) normal distribution!
str(icIni)

dmIni <- list(
  bare = numeric(), # past observations (at times 1, ..., t-1, t, t+1, ...)
  term = with(icIni, {leadtime + review}), # track blocks; 1 = no block
  blck = numeric() # past blocked observations 
)

fcIni <- list( # (initial) values for several parameters
  initOK  = FALSE, # has the list been properly initialized?
  smthpar = list(alpha = .2, beta = 0.1, gamma = 0.1),  # smoothing parameter
  other   = list(), # other stuff goes here (like for dlp/crs)
  latestfc = NA
)

fctIDs = c("dlp", "crs", "nai", "zer", "ses")
oulIDs = c("nAppr", "errQ", "nMod", "qMod", "bootM", "Eq8", "Eq9", "fxCst")
demIds <- c("bernoulliPoisson","geometricUniform", "normal" )

# 2 Pick scenarios, and set-up objects (for storing) ----
# scenarios
approaches <- list(oulid = oulIDs, fctid = fctIDs,
                   demid = demIds, blck = c("1", "b"))
scenarios <- cross_df(approaches)
rm(approaches, fctIDs, oulIDs, demIds)

scenarios
scenarios <-  mutate(scenarios, 
                     lt = icIni$leadtime, rt = icIni$review,
                     agg = ifelse(blck =="1", lt+rt, 1),
                     csl = icIni$csl)
scenarios <- mutate(scenarios, scnid = 
                      paste(oulid, fctid, blck, sep = "+"), .before = 1)
scenarios <- mutate(scenarios, fctidx = paste0(fctid, blck))
scenarios <- dataUnUsedInOul(scenarios) # adds variable usedinoul
scenarios <- setParameters4Dem(scenarios) # adds par. values for demand
scenarios

# select scenarios
myScenarios <- c("fxCst+crs+1","nAppr+dlp+b","errQ+nai+b",
                 "nMod+ses+b","Eq9+zer+1","bootM+crs+1") # example
myScenarios <- c("qMod+crs+1","qMod+dlp+1","bootM+crs+b","bootM+dlp+b")
tbFolder <- filter(scenarios, scnid %in% myScenarios)
tbFolder <- filter(scenarios, notinoul == "---")
tbFolder <- filter(scenarios, notinoul == "---"& demid == "bernoulliPoisson")
tbFolder
# tbFolder <- scenarios

# skeleton (empty) objects for keeping track of simulated values
# of forecasts and demands:
base1Store <- map_dfc(c("epoch", "dem", "blk"), 
                       setNames, object = list(as.numeric(NA)))
base1Store

# inventory levels, amounts shipped and ordered, ...
oneRecord <- map_dfc(c("per", "bopNS", "bopIP", "orderArrival", "avail2Ship",
                       "demand", "required", "shipped", "unserved", "eopNS", 
                       "eopIP", "canOrder", "orderPlaced", "oul"), 
                     setNames, object = list(as.numeric(NA)))

# fill initial (right before simulation starts) inventory record with values:
oneRecord <-  within(oneRecord, { orderPlaced <- eopNS <- eopIP <- 0 }) 
oneRecord

# constants: for length of time interval
numWarmUpForecasts <- 17
numInventorySimulations <- 2000

omnibus <- list() # collects all simulated data

# 3 Start Big Loop, picking one scenario at a time ----
tic("All loops:")
for (ii in 1:nrow(tbFolder)) { # ii <- 1; ii <- 2; ii <- 3
  cat("\n"); tic("This loop")
  dmStatus <- dmIni; fcStatus <- fcIni; icStatus <- icIni
  scenario1 <- as.list(slice(tbFolder,ii)) # 1 scenario as a list
  # str(scenario1)
  
  TellMe <- paste0("Simulating scenario ", ii)
  TellMe <- paste0(TellMe, " (",nrow(tbFolder),"): ", scenario1$scnid)
  print(paste0(TellMe, " under ", scenario1$demid, " demand."))
  
  demandFun <- with(scenario1, createRandomVariable(demid, par = c(par1, par2)))
  
  # draw enough demands such that forecast parameters can be initialized
  while (!fcStatus$initOK) {
    dmStatus <- processNewValue(demandFun(), dmStatus)
    if (scenario1$blck == "1"){
      obsVals <- dmStatus$bare
    } else { obsVals = dmStatus$blck } # if - else should not matter
    fcStatus <- initializeForecasting1(scenario1, obsVals, fcStatus)
  }
  
  startingPeriods4Casts <- length(dmStatus$bare) # using $blck: same result
  
  empty1Store <- mutate(base1Store, !! scenario1$fctidx := as.numeric(NA))
  empty1Store
  allStores <- slice(empty1Store, rep.int(1, startingPeriods4Casts))
  allStores <- mutate(allStores, epoch = 1 : startingPeriods4Casts, 
                      dem = dmStatus$bare, blk = dmStatus$blck)
  allStores
  
  # 3a Warming up: run forecast during warming up interval ----
  forecastFun <- create4CastFunction(scenario1$fctid, fcS = fcStatus)
  # and run forecasts on warming-up interval ...
  for (jj in (1 : numWarmUpForecasts)) { # jj <- 1
    t <- startingPeriods4Casts + jj # the current time period
    dmStatus <- processNewValue(demandFun(), dmStatus)
    oneStore <- update1Storage(t, dmStatus, forecastFun, 
                               scenario1, oneS = empty1Store)
    allStores <- bind_rows(allStores, oneStore)
  }
  allStores
  
  icStatus$aggreg <- scenario1$agg
  oulFun <- createOULRule(scenario1$oulid, xpar = icStatus)
  
  allRecords <- oneRecord # allRecords will expand and collect all records
  
  simStart <-  allStores[[nrow(allStores), "epoch"]] + 1
  simEnd <- simStart + numInventorySimulations
```